# Collatz and other sequences: how to get more precision easily and avoid segfault?

Tags: java, c, performance

Here's a simple C program I created from some old Java code (my first C program, so be nice ;) ). This runs much faster than the corresponding Java code, but Java allows me to be more precise (I'm using longs in Java, too) before it crashes.

To my surprise, the Java code doesn't crash until the input exceeds 170,000,000. The C code can't handle anything over 1,050,000. Any suggestions on making this C code run better without needing some crazy libraries? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* lets me use memset */
#include <stdlib.h> /* home of strtoull */

/* segfault 11 after 1047993 (Not anymore!!) */ 

unsigned long long getnext( unsigned long long x );

unsigned long long getnext( unsigned long long x )
{
    if (x == 1) { return 1; }
    if (x % 2 == 0) { return x/2; }
    return (3 * x + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int argind;
    for ( argind = 0; argind < argc; argind++ )
    {
        unsigned long long intrange;
        intrange = strtoull(argv[argind], NULL, 10);

       /** Improper allocation of memory. Fixed directly below. Thanks Marcus!
        * unsigned long long lengths[intrange+1];
        * memset(lengths, 0, sizeof(lengths));
        */ 

        unsigned long long *lengths= malloc((intrange+1) * sizeof(unsigned long long)); /* ptr points to mem. location of lengths array. */
        memset(lengths, 0, (intrange+1) * sizeof(unsigned long long));

        unsigned long long longestlen[2];
        unsigned long long seqindex;
        unsigned long long origdex;

        longestlen[0] = 0;
        longestlen[1] = 0;

        for (origdex = 2; origdex <= intrange; origdex++) 
        {
            seqindex = origdex;
            while ( seqindex > 1 )
            {
                lengths[ origdex ] += 1;
                seqindex = getnext(seqindex);

                if ( seqindex <= intrange )
                {
                    if ( lengths[ seqindex ] > 0)
                    {
                        lengths[ origdex ] =  lengths[ origdex ] + lengths[ seqindex ];
                        if ( lengths[origdex] > longestlen[1] ) { longestlen[0] = origdex; longestlen[1] = lengths[origdex]; }
                        seqindex = 1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(longestlen[0] > 0 ){ printf("Longest Collatz sequence for first %llu positive integers found at %llu with length %llu. \n", intrange, longestlen[0], longestlen[1]); }

    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I'll remove the compiler-construction tag; it's unrelated (your question is not about how to write a compiler).

Comment: `unsigned long long lengths[intrange+1];` might stack-overflow. make by malloc instead of.  also `argv[0]` is program name.

Comment: edited to add solution by Marcüs Muller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let your program run through a debugger (in my case:

```
gcc -o collatz -g collatz.c
gdb --args collatz 2000000
$run
...segfault at memset(lengths,0,sizeof(lengths))...
```

),
you'll see that your segfault happens when you try to access lengths!

The point is that you're doing dynamic memory allocation for arrays wrong; that's a bit tricky in C (which is why I generally recommend that people coming from other languages learn a modern C++ rathern than C).

You should do

```
unsigned long long *lengths = malloc(...);
```

to give you freshly allocated memory.

Also, `sizeof(lengths)` then is wrong, since that would be the size of the pointer to the address of the beginning of your array. Use `sizeof(unsigned long long)` instead. Of course, your code then must read `memset(lengths, 0, sizeof(unsigned long long)*(intrange+1))` to set the `intrange+1` times the amount of bytes an `unsigned long long` occupies to the `0` byte.

For details on `malloc`, you can use `man malloc` if you're on a system that has `man`; generally, you have to "release" the memory you allocate using `malloc` after usage. In your case, upon termination of the program it's done automatically, but for more complex software, not calling `free(ptr)` on what you've acquired by `type *ptr = malloc(...)` after you no longer need that memory is a memory leak.

Again, that's a very typical C problem. If you write your code in C++, you will, at nearly no performance penalty at all, get the ability to use things like `std::vector` to give you variable-sized arrays with automatic construction and value fill, which will automatically be deallocated upon leaving the scope in which it was declared.

Comment: @honk: But that really was my last edit to this answer :)

Comment: I no longer see the need to edit anything anyway ;) I think now you wrote a perfect answer! I'm happy that I could assist you on that, you have my upvote. I deleted my obsolete comments; maybe you can do the same to keep the comments section clean :) I'm sorry, I just love to be professional ;)

Comment: @honk: Having reached perfection, I know transcend to a higher level of being :) thanks!

Comment: Thank you Marcus Müler. It now works for larger numbers! Is the "plus one" in (intrange+1) necessary or can it be left out? I accidentally ran the code without the plus one and it worked. Also, the signature for memset has the first argument as a void *ptr. Is lengths a *ptr type? I thought it just the array itself, and not the pointer to an address.

Comment: Got somewhere around 250,000,000 in a few seconds. Tried to go one significant figure higher and the system ran out of memory in a few minutes running the program. If I want to do better, would you recommend periodically clearing the lengths array and renaming the first index to the next highest number? I'm realizing that an array with billions of containers is unreasonable (but 100 million isn't so bad).

Comment: @awalllllll: Arrays can be understood as pointer to their first element. C doesn't internally know how long an array is, so you must carry around its length in a separate variable. That's basic C, so you might want to read a tutorial on C arrays.

Comment: @awalllllll: you shouldn't allocate a big array at all if your algorithm can work on smaller ones, but that's a criticism on the algorithm itself, not on your implementation.

Comment: Right, no such thing as an OutOfBoundsException in C - thanks!